# How to pass a bound model to an inputs action method

Tags: ember.js

I have an input inside my handlebars template

```
{{#each thing in controller}}
  {{input action="update_model" class="blue"}}
{{/each}}
```

This will intercept the "enter key" correctly, but I need to pass my "thing" model to the update action, how can I do this w/ the latest build of ember.js ?

```
actions: {
  update_model: function(model) {
    //do something w/ the model even when the user hits enter
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do when the enter key is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but this should work:

```
{{#each thing in controller}}
  {{view App.CustomView class="blue" action="update_model" controller=controller param=thing }}
{{/each}}

App.CustomView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  keyPress:function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      this.get("controller").send(this.get("action"), this.get("param"))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: nice -it's something at the moment anyway